# Open iCloud Drive in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud, icloud-drive

I want to allow document(pdf, doc, docx) selection in my app. And I want to integrate iCloud for this. All I want to do is to open the iCloud drive from my app and there user can select the file and returns back to the origin app. Something like whatsapp has done for document selection in iOS app.

Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 18):

Read this below link you will get idea: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html

Below is the code :

```
-(IBAction)iCloudDriveFullFolder:(id)sender{
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                                                                                                                inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
        documentPicker.delegate = self;

  documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - iCloud files
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
        //  NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully imported %@", [url lastPathComponent]];
        //do stuff

    }
}
```

Comment: Dude thanks so much for this, I've been stuck on this problem for so long and I cam across this and everything worked! THANK YOU!